# When should I use nonlinear-regression model

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression

I have the following table:

```
d <- read.table(textConnection("y x1 x2 x3 x4
                  40 5 10 8 2 
                  60 9 19 9 9 
                  75 18 27 19 5 
                  80 15 36 25 20 
                  115 25 45 39 30 
                  120 35 48 40 19"), header=TRUE)
```

I did linear regression analysis:

```
summary(lm(y~., data=d))

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 30.50427    7.24960   4.208    0.149
x1           2.46856    1.13807   2.169    0.275
x2          -0.04313    0.91344  -0.047    0.970
x3          -0.45983    1.01308  -0.454    0.729
x4           1.35522    0.82608   1.641    0.348

Residual standard error: 4.855 on 1 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9951,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9756 
F-statistic: 51.02 on 4 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.1046
```

How can I figure out if I need to do nonlinear-regression analysis or not?

Comment: In general, I'd only consider using a non-linear model if I had a scientific justification supporting it. If your model building is purely empirical and a linear OLS model (or a GLM) is not sufficient, you could try using a GAM. However, you need a sufficient number of observations in any case.

Comment: Just a comment to @Roland that the "sufficient number of observations" should not steer one toward thinking that OLS/linear regression/regression with only linear terms has higher power in general than a nonlinear regression (e.g. GAM): misspecifying a model by using a straight line to represent a curved relationship in the data can hemorrhage statistical power.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing a regression with only 6 observations and 4 explanatory variables. That is way too much explanatory variables for that dataset. So, if anything you should make your model simpler rather than make it more complex by adding non-linearity. In fact, with only 6 observations I would probably limit myself to only one explanatory variable.